# Azure Storage Account - Prepare for a failover fails with "Last sync time is unavailable"

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

I have an Azure Storage Account of type "RA-GRS" as shown below

[image]

WEST US is being Primary and East US is secondary.

While trying to failover to East US it is failing as shown below

[image]

How to fix this?

Note: I have followed this article - [Prepare for a failover](https://samcogan.com/customer-initiated-storage-account-failover/)

Comment: Is that a limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/56128) where account failover is not possible within 4 hours of account creation or the conversion to (RA-)GRS. Either one of these conditions will cause the error you mention.

> we currently have an ongoing issue with account failover wherein it can only be initiated once LastSyncTime is more than 4 hours after account creation time or after the time the account was converted to (RA-)GRS. E.g. if the account was created at 1 pm, then the LST should be 5 pm in order for the failover to work. We're working on the resolution right now, but I don't have the ETA quite yet.

You should also [check the last sync time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/last-sync-time-get) just to make sure this is available.

```
$lastSyncTime = $(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <resource-group> `
    -Name <storage-account> `
    -IncludeGeoReplicationStats).GeoReplicationStats.LastSyncTime
```

Comment: The storage account is created at least 15 days before with (RA-)GRS option and  WEST US as a primary